# Can Someone Explain me the below PHP Code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please, Anyone, explain to me this condition, I did not get it.
Code is Properly Working, But I forget what logic I used to return the value.

```
$chkBlock = Blocked::where("block_username", "=", Auth::user()->username)
                    ->where("user_username", "=", $username)
                    ->count();

if ($chkBlock > 0) {
    return \Redirect::back()->withSuccess( 'This User Block you' );
}
```

Comment: In laravel when you wrote query in this eloquent way ,it will go to the Blocked model and from that it's having table name in model and from table it goes to find block_username  equal to Current loggedin username and from user_username field found $username and return count() means total number of data it fetched give the count of that.
And if count is more than 0 means 1 than it will redirecting to the same page with success message.

Answer (score 1):

```
Blocked::where("block_username", "=", Auth::user()->username)
                    ->where("user_username", "=", $username)
                    ->count();
```

this is SQL query it will return the count of records based on condition.

```
if ($chkBlock > 0) {
    return \Redirect::back()->withSuccess( 'This User Block you' );
}
```

this will check if the count is greater then 0 then redirect to the previous page with success message.

Answer (score 1):

In this, you are fetching data from the `Blocked` model to check whether the user is blocked or not.

For this, you are simply passing the current login username (`Auth::user()->username`) and you gave another user name too (`$username`).

```
$chkBlock = Blocked::where("block_username", "=", Auth::user()->username)
                    ->where("user_username", "=", $username)
                    ->count();
```

What this query is doing is checking if the `blockeds` table has any row containing the current user and given username (`$username`) and getting a count.

So now is the second query:

```
if ($chkBlock > 0) {
    return \Redirect::back()->withSuccess( 'This User Block you' );
}
```

You are checking whether the `rowCount` got an entry or not. If count is 1 or more than 0 means the user is blocked and you are redirecting back with the message `This User Block you`

If you want to see what MySQL query is running, you can simply use:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
//Your Model query goes here
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

It will die and dump the MySQL query.